# Scraping from a webpage table into a data frame in R

Tags: r

I am learning to import tables from websites into R studio. I would like to get the data into a data frame. The data is coming into R with the class as "xml document" "xml_node". How do I convert this into a simple data frame to manipulate?

```
mlb <- read_html("https://www.mlb.com/stats/team")
mlb %>%
html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

The column headers are coming though twice as well and I don't know why.

Comment: I recommend you don't try to scrape the html (though it's certainly possible). Instead, in your web-browser, open up the dev-console, switch to the network tab of it, then reload the page. Look for all pages of type `json`, and you'll see that you can get the data much more directly, such as calls to https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/mlb-stats/team/2022/en-US?&contextTeamId= and https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/team?stitch_env=prod&sportId=1&gameType=R&group=hitting&order=desc&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&stats=season&season=2022&limit=30&offset=0

Comment: Pull those and parse them with `jsonlite::parse_json`, then you'll have to work a bit to convert sub-lists to sub-frames, etc.

Comment: Alternatively, just `df <- mlb %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
  .[[1]]

colnames(df) <- str_sub(colnames(df), start = 1, end = str_length(colnames(df)) / 2)` as it seemse that the names are just duplicated.